# Need help with sending Arduino data to web page with ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, lm35

I am developing a system that reads data from an LM35 temperature sensor and forwards it to a web page using an Arduino Uno and a ESP8266 WiFi Module. The data flow is as follows:

`LM35 --> Arduino Uno --> ESP8266 (Having a web server) --> Webpage`

The Uno sends data to the ESP8266 every `SAMPLE_RATE` seconds (4 seconds in my example) but the ESP8266 keeps updating the web page as it is a dynamic web page running AJAX. The problem is that I can see the data updating only once in a while (I assume when the 4 second delay aligns with the instant when the ESP8266 updates the value on the web page).

How can I make it so that even if The Uno doesn't send new values (during the 4 second gap), the ESP8266 keeps updating the web page with the old values? I have tried numerous times but have failed. Here is my code so far:

ARDUINO SIDE:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <String.h>

//a Header for the Filtering Algorithm

//*******************************************************************/
//#include "Filter.h"
//*******************************************************************/

//Set RESET PIN for ESP8266

//*******************************************************************/
#define RST_PIN_ESP8266 13
//*******************************************************************/

//Define Baud rate for Serial Communication and ESP8266 Software Serial
//*******************************************************************/
#define SERIAL_BAUD_RATE 9600
#define ESP8266_SOFT_SERIAL_BAUD_RATE 9600
//*******************************************************************/

//LM35 Temperature sensor used for this code
//*******************************************************************/
#define LM35 A0
//*******************************************************************/

//Define Sensor sampling rate
//*******************************************************************/
#define SAMPLE_RATE 4000
//*******************************************************************/

//Code Features . . Uncomment to enable
//*******************************************************************/
//#define LM35_RAW_DEBUG
//#define TEMP_READ
//#define PRINT_DEBUG
#define MEASURE_SALINE
//*******************************************************************/
//ESP8266 Software Serial Object
//*******************************************************************/
SoftwareSerial ESP8266_Serial(6,7);
//*******************************************************************/

//Global Variables
//*******************************************************************/
float tempC;
long rawValue = 0, initCount = 0;
int initRawValue = 0, i, START_VALUE = 0;
int SALINE_STARTED = 0, SALINE_IN_PROGRESS = 1, SALINE_EXHAUSTED = 2;
int saline_status_flag = 0;
String finalMSG;
//*******************************************************************/

//Needed objects for time counting and filtering
//*******************************************************************/
unsigned long StartTime = millis();
//ExponentialFilter<int> ADCFilter(5, 0);
//*******************************************************************/

void setup() {
  long rawValue = 0, initCount = 0;
  int initRawValue = 0, i;
  //Set up Serial Communication
  Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD_RATE);
  ESP8266_Serial.begin(ESP8266_SOFT_SERIAL_BAUD_RATE);
  pinMode(RST_PIN_ESP8266, OUTPUT);
  Reset_ESP8266();
  while(ESP8266_Serial.available()) {
    getIP();  // Obtain IP for ESP8266
  }
  delay(1000);
  //Increase accuracy
  analogReference(INTERNAL);
  //Start Sensor Calibration
  #ifdef MEASURE_SALINE
    Serial.print(". . . CALIBRATING SYSTEM . . .\n");
    #ifdef PRINT_DEBUG
      Serial.println("\n\nTime Elapsed  :\n\n");
    #endif

    here:
    unsigned long currentTime = millis();
    unsigned long elapsedTime = currentTime - StartTime;

    #ifdef PRINT_DEBUG
      Serial.println(elapsedTime);
    #endif

    if(elapsedTime < 20000) {
      initCount++;
      rawValue += analogRead(LM35);
      #ifdef PRINT_DEBUG
        Serial.println(rawValue);
      #endif 
      goto here;
    }
    currentTime = 0;
    elapsedTime = 0;
    rawValue = rawValue / initCount;
    //Averaging from 5000 sensor samples
    initRawValue = rawValue;
    START_VALUE = initRawValue;
    Serial.println("\n. . . CALIBRATION COMPLETE . . .");
    Serial.print("\nInitial Raw LM35 Value  : ");
    Serial.print(START_VALUE);
    Serial.print("\n\n");
    Reinitialize_Variables();
    delay(2000);

    #ifdef PRINT_DEBUG
      Serial.println("\nLM35 Sample Count:\n");
      Serial.println(initCount);
    #endif

  #endif
  initCount = 0;

  #ifdef LM35_RAW_DEBUG
    Serial.println("\n. . . STARTING LM35 DEBUG READING . . .\n\n");
  #endif

  #ifdef MEASURE_SALINE
    Serial.println("\n. . . STARTING SALINE MONITORING. . .\n\n");
  #endif
}

void loop() {
  #ifdef MEASURE_SALINE
    Measure_Saline();
  #endif

  #ifdef LM35_RAW_DEBUG
    rawValue = analogRead(LM35);
    Serial.println(rawValue);
  #endif

  #ifdef TEMP_READ
    Read_Temp();
  #endif

  Reinitialize_Variables();
}

void Measure_Saline() {
  int dont_print_flag = 0;
  unsigned long StartTime = millis();
  //Take readings (SAMPLE_RATE times) and average them
  here:
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  unsigned long elapsedTime = currentTime - StartTime;

  #ifdef PRINT_DEBUG
    Serial.println(elapsedTime);
  #endif

  if(elapsedTime < SAMPLE_RATE) {
    initCount++;
    rawValue += analogRead(LM35);
    #ifdef PRINT_DEBUG
      Serial.println(rawValue);
    #endif
    goto here;
  }
  currentTime = 0;
  elapsedTime = 0;
  rawValue = rawValue / initCount;

  #ifdef PRINT_DEBUG
    Serial.print("initCount  : ");
    Serial.print(initCount);
  #endif
  if(saline_status_flag != SALINE_EXHAUSTED) {
    if(rawValue < START_VALUE) {
      saline_status_flag = SALINE_STARTED;
    } else if(rawValue == START_VALUE) {
      saline_status_flag = SALINE_IN_PROGRESS;
    } else if(rawValue > START_VALUE) {
      START_VALUE = rawValue;
      delay(1000);
      rawValue = analogRead(LM35);
      delay(10);
      if(rawValue > START_VALUE) {
        saline_status_flag = SALINE_EXHAUSTED;
        dont_print_flag = 1;
        Serial.print(rawValue);
        Serial.print("  Saline bottle EXHAUSTED\n");
        finalMSG = (String(rawValue) + " EXHAUSTED\n");
        ESP8266_Serial.println(finalMSG);
      }
    }
    //Saline Therapy Ongoing
    if((saline_status_flag == SALINE_STARTED || saline_status_flag == SALINE_IN_PROGRESS) && dont_print_flag == 0) {
      Serial.print(rawValue);
      Serial.print("  Saline Therapy IN PROGRESS\n");
      finalMSG = (String(rawValue) + " IN PROGRESS\n");
      ESP8266_Serial.println(finalMSG);
    } else if(saline_status_flag == SALINE_EXHAUSTED && dont_print_flag == 0) {
      //Saline Exhausted
      Serial.print(rawValue);
      Serial.print("  Saline bottle EXHAUSTED\n");
      finalMSG = (String(rawValue) + " EXHAUSTED\n");
      ESP8266_Serial.println(finalMSG);
    }
    START_VALUE = rawValue;
  } else {
    Serial.print("  Saline bottle EXHAUSTED\n");
    finalMSG = (String(rawValue) + " EXHAUSTED\n");
    ESP8266_Serial.println(finalMSG);
  }
  delay(200);
}

void Read_Temp() {
  rawValue = analogRead(LM35);
  tempC = rawValue * 0.48828125;
  tempC = rawValue / 9.31;
  Serial.println(tempC);
  delay(2000);
}

void Reinitialize_Variables() {
  initCount = 0;
  rawValue = 0;
  initRawValue = 0;
  i = 0;
}

void getIP() {
  Serial.println(ESP8266_Serial.readStringUntil('\n'));
}

void Reset_ESP8266() {
  pinMode(RST_PIN_ESP8266, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RST_PIN_ESP8266, HIGH);
  // (RST_PIN_ESP8266 = 1 -> RESET = 0 so ESP8266 RESET FALSE)  
  delay(1000);             
  digitalWrite(RST_PIN_ESP8266, LOW);
  // (RST_PIN_ESP8266 = 0 -> RESET = 1 so ESP8266 RESET TRUE)
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(RST_PIN_ESP8266, HIGH);
  // (RST_PIN_ESP8266 = 1 -> RESET = 0 so ESP8266 RESET FALSE)
  delay(50);
}
```

ESP8266 side:

```
/*
 * This Code is for the ESP8266 WiFi Module. It builds a website running AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML)
 * which allows this webpage to update itself without having to refresh itself which may not be resource friendly
 */

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#define DEVICE_ID 1

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
const char* ssid="COLDSPOT";  // WiFi Access Point to connect to
const char* password="1234567890"; // Password for the Access Point
String webSite,javaScript,XML;

void buildWebsite() {
  buildJavascript();
  webSite = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n";
  webSite += javaScript;
  webSite += "<BODY onload='process()'>\n";
  webSite += "<h1 align='center'><BR>SALINE MONITORING:<BR><h1>\n";
  webSite += "STATUS = <A id='runtime'></A>\n";
  webSite += "</BODY>\n";
  webSite += "</HTML>\n";
}

void buildJavascript() {
  javaScript = "<SCRIPT>\n";
  javaScript += "var xmlHttp=createXmlHttpObject();\n";
  javaScript += "function createXmlHttpObject(){\n";
  javaScript += " if(window.XMLHttpRequest){\n";
  javaScript += "    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();\n";
  javaScript += " }else{\n";
  javaScript += "    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');\n";
  javaScript += " }\n";
  javaScript += " return xmlHttp;\n";
  javaScript += "}\n";
  javaScript += "function process(){\n";
  javaScript += " if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){\n";
  javaScript += "   xmlHttp.open('PUT','xml',true);\n";
  javaScript += "   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponse;\n"; // no brackets?????
  javaScript += "   xmlHttp.send(null);\n";
  javaScript += " }\n";
  javaScript += " setTimeout('process()',1000);\n";
  javaScript += "}\n";
  javaScript += "function handleServerResponse(){\n";
  javaScript += " if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){\n";
  javaScript += "   xmlResponse=xmlHttp.responseXML;\n";
  javaScript += "   xmldoc = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName('response');\n";
  javaScript += "   message = xmldoc[0].firstChild.nodeValue;\n";
  javaScript += "   document.getElementById('runtime').innerHTML=message;\n";
  javaScript += " }\n";
  javaScript += "}\n";
  javaScript += "</SCRIPT>\n";
}

void buildXML() {
  XML = "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
  XML += "<response>";
  XML += DataFromArduino(); //incoming data from Arduino. It means it is the value of mapping function.
  XML += "</response>";
}

String DataFromArduino() {
  String coming;
  if(Serial.available()) {
    while(Serial.available()) {
      coming = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
      delay(1);
    } // it is getting via serial port.
    return coming;
  } else {
    return coming;
  }
}

void handleWebsite() {
  buildWebsite();
  server.send(200,"text/html",webSite);
}

void handleXML() {
  buildXML();
  server.send(200,"text/xml",XML);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);  //trying to connect the modem
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println("\n\n. . . BOOTING ESP8266 . . .\n");
  Serial.print("DEVICE ID : ");
  Serial.print(DEVICE_ID);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print("CONNECTED TO ACCESS POINT :  ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.flush();
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  //it is sending the IP to Arduino's port. So I can see the IP on Serial Monitor
  Serial.flush();
  server.on("/", handleWebsite);
  //it is all about setting of server.
  server.on("/xml",handleXML);
  server.begin();  
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Please note that I have already changed the baud rate of the ESP8266 to 9600. I am using [THIS ESP8266](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678) Module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the variable `String coming` out of the function `DataFromArduino()` and make it a global variable (by adding it to the line after String website1).  That way it will store its value between calls to  `DataFromArduino()` and return the same result if it has had nothing new.